# Display NEXT and PREVIOUS pagination?

Tags: pagination, previous, next

I need help on the pagination. I try to put the NEXT and PREVIOUS pagination that show the post in a same category, but I am not sure what happen that showing nothing.

If you can help, much thanks!

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="page">
    <?php 
    $previous_post = get_previous_post('%link', 'Next post in category', TRUE);
    if ( $previous_post ) : ?>

    <!-- [ PREVIOUS ITEM ]-->
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail( $previous_post->ID ) ) : ?>
    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $previous_post->ID, 'gallery-navigation' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $previous_post->ID ); ?>"><div class="info">
    <div class="info-gallery">
    <h2 class="title"><?php echo $previous_post->post_title; ?></h2>
    </div><!-- .info-content -->
    </div></a><!---info -->

    <span class="prevnext"><?php _e( 'Previous Featured', ); ?></span></div>
    <?php endif; //End of Previous Post Item ?>

    <?php $next_post = get_next_post('%link', 'Next post in category', TRUE);
    if ( $next_post ) : ?>

    <!-- [ NEXT ITEM ]-->
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail( $next_post->ID ) ) { 
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $next_post->ID, 'gallery-navigation' ); }?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $next_post->ID ); ?>"><div class="info">
    <div class="info-gallery">
    <h2 class="title"><?php echo $next_post->post_title; ?></h2>
    </div><!-- .info-content -->
    </div></a><!-- -info -->

    <span class="prevnext"><?php _e( 'Next Featured'); ?></span></div>
    <?php endif; //End of Next Post Item ?>

    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_previous_post()` and `get_next_post()` are deprecated. You should use `get_previous_post_link()` and `get_next_post_link()` or even better the wrapper functions `the_post_navigation()` or `get_the_post_navigation()`. If you don't know how to use them, see the **single.php** template of the twentyfifteen theme that comes with WordPress by default. You can also see how these functions are implemented in the **link-template.php** file located in the **wp-includes** folder.